# Como hacer desaparecer letras y numero de dashboard

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tengo un grafico con chart.js, alguien me puede decir como hacer desaparecer los números de la parte izquierda y las letras de la parte inferior del dashboard en forma de dona.
Imagen de lo que deseo ocultar:https://ibb.co/hR9PLTT
Imagen de lo que quiero: https://ibb.co/rc41tNJ
Por ejemplo para hacer desaparecer las líneas es: gridLines: false

```js
                // Configuration options go here
                options: {
                  
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                          gridLines: false
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                          gridLines: false
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes distintas maneras de lograr lo que quieres, pero en todos los casos, lo que tienes que deshabilitar es `showXAxisLabel`, en este caso para quitar los de abajo, para quitar los de la izquiera serían los del eje Y.

**Primera opción**

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
             ticks: {
                 display: false
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

**Segunda opción**

```
options: {
    scales: {
      x: {  // En este caso es un objeto en vez de un array (Primera opción)
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }
   }
}
```

**Tercera opción** Con JavaScript directamente. (mi favorita)

```
newChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = false;
```

En caso de que ninguna opción te funcione, te recomiendo buscar información en ingles sobre `showXAxisLabel`, te aparecerán distintas opciones de conseguir lo que quieres. También deberas de quitar el del eje `Y`, utilizando `yAxes` en lugar de `xAxes`